# Find a set of documents in collection A, based on an array from collection B

Tags: mongodb

**The following data needs to be stored in MongoDb:**

A collection of *persons* (approximately 100-2000) together with their relevant attributes. 
Another collection of *queues* (approximately 5-50).

Information about the *relationsship between persons and queues*. Each person can stand in line in several queues, and each queue can hold several persons. The order of the persons waiting in a queue is important.

Currently this is what i have in mind:

*Persons:*

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("507c35dd8fada716c89d0001"),
  first_name: 'john',
  email: 'john.doe@doe.com'
  id_number: 8101011234,
  ... 
},
```

*Queues:*

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("507c35dd8fada716c89d0011"),
  title: 'A title for this queue',
  people_waiting: [
    ObjectId("507c35dd8fada716c89d0001"),
    ObjectId("507c35dd8fada716c89d0002"), 
    ObjectId("507c35dd8fada716c89d0003"), 
    ...
  ]
},
```

In a web page, I want to list (in order) all persons standing in a certain queue. I'm thinking that I first need to query the 'people_waiting' array from the 'Queues' collection. And then loop trough this array and for each item query it from the 'Persons' collection.

But there seems to be a lot of queries to generate this list, and i wonder if there is a smarter way to write/combine queries than the way described above.

Comment: Not sure what your question is here, I think you might need to show an expected result. Your structure on queues is also not valid. The other suspicion is that you are asking for joins, which is something MongoDB does not do.

Comment: Hmm... have i written something wrong in the Queues document?
I this was a RDBMS, the ansver to this question would be joins, yes. But it's Mongodb, and it doesn't support joins as you says. So my Questions is: How do i Query all persons in a certain queue, and in the correct order?.... in MongoDb style.

Comment: You don't need to repeat yourself as your return comment really doesn't say anything that is not in the question. The comment from me asked you to clarify your question and explain what you want from "query the persons". Currently your question does not explain this. This is what comments are for.

Comment: In a web page, I want to list (in order) all persons standing in a certain queue. I'm thinking that I first need to query and save the 'people_waiting' array from the 'Queues' collection. And then loop trough this array and for each item query it from the 'Persons' collection. Part of my questions is also if there is another better way to write/combine the queries, or re arrange the data for simpler queries.  

I hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Arrays are ordered, so we all get that part. But again you seem to be asking something like "finding certain people" or basically "joining person information" with your array. But really all I am asking you to do is edit your question to make your intentions clear. Your comments are not improving this and people should not need to read through comments to work out what you are asking. If you have a specific result in mind then make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only query one collection at a time in MongoDB, so it does take two queries.  But you can use `$in` instead of looping through array and querying each person individually.

In the shell:

```js
queue = db.Queues.findOne({_id: idOfQueue});
peopleWaiting = db.Persions.find({_id: {$in: queue.people_waiting}}).toArray();
```

But `peopleWaiting` will not be sorted by the order of the ids in the queue and there's no support for doing that in a MongoDB query.  So you'd have to reorder `peopleWaiting` in your code to match the order in `queue.people_waiting`.